# How to instantiate View from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, user-interface, mvvm

Events occur in our Model and ViewModel that necessitate creating the appropriate View. The question is how to do this and avoid having any View code in the VM or M?

Here's the sequence of events so you can see this dilemma:

The user sets a number fields in a form to start a long running background process and then clicks the "Start" button.  If this long running process succeeds then it needs to popup a chart with graphs to show the results. However, if the data fails processing for any reason then it can't popup charts, instead it logs an error message which is show in the a text box on the form.

Right now, that start button calls a method in the ViewModel which actually starts the background thread.

Only the background can determine when or if to create the view.

Currently we have this working by using an interface called ChartInterface. The view implements this interface and then sets a callback delegate all the way down to the backend model.  When it decides to create the Chart it invokes the callback and uses the interface to pass the appropriate data and such.

However, this presents a problem because it can potentially produce dozens or hundreds of charts. So we need to have a "Dashboard" with a list of all the charts for the user to select which one to see.

So now the backend needs to decide when or if to create the Dashboard View, then add Chart View to it.

So it's getting messier because there will be increasingly more of these situations as we have lots of Models that need views so creating tons of callback delegates gets ugly fast.

An idea that seems to simplify instead of lots of callbacks will be to only pass an interface to a ViewBinder to the backend. Then each time it creates a model object, it can pass it to the ViewBinder to see if it wants to bind any view object to it.

Our thinking is that most any of the backend objects will be interesting (eventually) to monitor graphically.  So if everyone of them after contructing is passed to the ViewBinder interface, then the view can decide if it wants to bind anything to it.

This is sounding better all the time.

Comment: My approach would be that the background process should create a ViewModel of the results rather than a View.

Comment: @hyp. Sorry it wasn't clear. It does create a Model and a ViewModel. But how to then cause the View to get created and bound to it? The trouble is that nothing in the View layer knows when this needs to happen. Only the backe nd knows when it's time to create and bind a view to the ViewModel.

Comment: Right, so if you have a ViewModel with results the according View should be created as any other one. Not sure how you do it with your other ViewModels but I always assume the service based path. In other words you've got a service which you throw a VM at and it loads the appropriate View. A MVVM framework would make it easier for you, I would recommend "Catel" @ http://catel.codeplex.com/ . Hope this helps

Comment: @hyp Yes. We started with some framework, I forget the name. But we can't use any static objects for ServiceLocator. We need dependency injection. Still, you confirmed my theory and I'll just create an interface that the View can pass to the ViewModel like ModelBinderInterface.

Answer (score 0):

The answer became clear while working on the code.

public interface ModelBinderInterface {
    void TryBind( object model);
}

instead of one global "server locator" it's more natural for EVERY view object to implement this interface.

Then when it creates any ViewModel objects it assigns itself to the ModelBinder property of the the viewModel object.

Now the ViewModel can pass this same interface to the back end process.

When ever any relevant model gets instantiated, then it calls the ModelBinder with the object.

Then the View object can decide if it can instantiate the object, if not, it can pass the call up to it's parent which also implements ModelBinderInterface.

This way each view can handle instantiating views that it understand whether that be adding a control to a DataGridView or binding the object to a ListView, etc.

Of course, this still allows for a singleton ModelBinder because the lower levels can keep handing the call up to the top level application ModelBinder which there's only one and it can offer singleton instances.